# I need another phrase for "as expected" or "it would follow"?

Tags: phrases

I am writing a technical paper where I have described an experiment resulting in "x".  Then I go on to describe the result of a second experiment whose result was expected since the reason was deduced in the previous experiment (x).  I'm looking for a phrase to tie the two sentences together but I did not want to use "as expected" or "it would follow".

I know there is another phrase out there that suits better but I can't seem to come up with it right now so I need your help.  Thanks.

Comment: Similar to "as expected" are "predictably," "as anticipated," and "not surprisingly." Similar to "it would follow" are "consequently" and "therefore."

Answer (score 3):

Consider [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/consistent) of *[consistent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistent#Adjective)*, such as *[compatible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compatible#Adjective)* and *[congruent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/congruent#Adjective)*; eg, “Results of experiment B were consistent / compatible / congruent with those of experiment A.”  Also consider *[in accord with](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accord#Noun)*; eg, “In accord with predictions based on experiment A, experiment B showed that...”

Answer (score 1):

"**Confirming the hypothesis**" always sounds good in a technical paper. Or "**as hypothesized**".

If you are noting agreement with previous results, you can say "**validating/confirming results from...**".

Answer (score 0):

"Corollary" is the usual technical/scientific term to describe the consequent or expected sets of derivative results or conclusions of a main theory, hypothesis or experiment.

> [cor·ol·lar·y](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corollary)  (kôr-lr, kr-)
>   n. pl. cor·ol·lar·ies
>
> 1. A proposition that follows with little or no proof required from one already proven.
> 2. A deduction or an inference.
> 3. A natural consequence or effect; a result.
>
> adj.
>   Consequent; resultant.

For example,

> I have thus concluded the 1st and 2nd experiments. The results of the 2nd experiment have demonstrated to be corollaries to those of the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

How about: clearly, apparently, obviously, evidently, patently?

The word obviously can sometimes affect readers adversely, "well, it wasn't so obvious to me."

Answer (score 0):

**Paralleled**

> a person or thing that is similar or analogous to another.

The experimental results **paralleled** the theoretically expected results outlined in Paper/Report/Experiment x/y/z

Alternatively:

- Corresponded
- Analogous

The correct word choice would also depend on the way the information is presented to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is **corroborate**:

> [**corroborate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corroborate): to
>   support or help prove (a statement, theory, etc.) by providing information or evidence

So, you performed a first experiment resulting in "x". The result "x" supports your hypothesis. You then perform a second experiment that, if the results of your first experiment are correct, will support the results of your first experiment. If that turns out to be the case, you would say that the results of your second experiment **corroborate** the results of your first experiment, and, thereby, strengthen the evidence in support of your hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Sure enough

[According to Oxford:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sure)

> Sure enough: used to introduce a statement that confirms something previously predicted.
>   "when X-rays were taken, sure enough, there was the needle" ; "The story was always going to be a sitter for the Sunday papers and, sure enough, all three gave it space."

Answer (score 0):

The primary question asks for a **linking phrase** for a discussion of "***expected***" results from a secondary experiment. You could say the results of the second experiment were "***anticipated***".

> The results of the second experiment were "**anticipated in support
>   of**" deductions made during the first experiment.

The second experiment was thus also **anticipated to affirm** the working deduction of the primary experiment. It could be referred to as **confirmatory** as well.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affirm

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/confirm

Answer (score -1):

If the results of your second experiment were predicted by the first experiment then there was no need to carry the former. Maybe you deduced from the first experiment's results that the second experiment might give certain results, or you had doubts about the reasons for the results of the first experiment. In this case, maybe,  *as predicted* is the wrong expression.

> What about *as indicated*?

Answer (score -1):

"Therefore it proves that" also passes off in a technical paper.

Answer (score -1):

[Ergo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ergo)

> :  therefore, hence

(definition from m-w.com)

Comment: Ergo, why? What does ergo mean? There are many things one could write instead of just adding dots.

Comment: @Ken, I took the liberty of expanding your answer to include the definition of the suggested word.  Feel free to edit further if you want to provide more details on how the word suits the need.